# How can I simulate a print queue generating and printing tasks C++?

Tags: c++, printing

I wrote a print queue algorithm that generates print jobs with a random number of pages, inserts the print jobs in a priority queue and then prints them. The program simulates printing times for systems with 1, 2, 3, and 4 printers. Print jobs are generated every 30 seconds and print jobs are printed at a rate of 7 pages/min.

The problem with my program is that it only creates a new print job once the first one finished printing, instead of continuing to generate new jobs every 30 seconds while previous jobs are printing at a rate of 7 pages/min. I have the time simulated with loops that increment once per second, but that doesn't seem to control the time like it should. **How can I control for time in both functions simultaneously so print jobs don't stop generating while the printer is printing?**

Here's my function that creates print jobs every 30 seconds:

```
void PrinterSim::startSimulation(int jobs, int printers)
{
  totalJobs = jobs; // total number of print jobs to generate
  numPrinters = printers;
  int tick = 1,
  jobInterval = 30; // generate new print job every 30 sec.
  for (int i = 0; i < totalJobs; i++)
  {
    int time = 0;
    while (time < jobInterval)
    time += tick;
    if (printers == 1)
    {
      // create new print job and insert into print queue
      // and into a vector storing jobs in the order they arrived
      PrintJob* newJob;
      newJob = new PrintJob;
      myQueue.setOrderReceived(newJob);
      myQueue.insertPrintQ(newJob);
    }
      else
    {
      // simulate same set of print jobs so get print job
      // from vector containing print jobs in order they arrived
      PrintJob* job = myQueue.getOrderReceived(i);
      myQueue.insertPrintQ(job);
    }
      // run simulation calls printerManager function
      runSimulation();
    }
  }
```

Here's the function that checks on printer status and sends print jobs to next available printer:

```
void PrintQueue::printerManager(int printers)
{
  while (!printQueue.empty())
  {
    // check status of each printer
    if (printer1.printerAvail())
    {
      printer1.startPrint(printQueue.top());
      orderPrinted.push_back(printQueue.top());
      printQueue.pop();
    }
    // simulation running with 2 or more printers
    // make use of multiple printers while first one
    // is busy
    else if (printer2.printerAvail() && printers > 1)
    {
      printer2.startPrint(printQueue.top());
      orderPrinted.push_back(printQueue.top());
      printQueue.pop();
    }
    else if (printer3.printerAvail() && printers > 2)
    {
      printer3.startPrint(printQueue.top());
      orderPrinted.push_back(printQueue.top());
      printQueue.pop();
    }
    else if (printer4.printerAvail() && printers == 4)
    {
      printer4.startPrint(printQueue.top());
      orderPrinted.push_back(printQueue.top());
      printQueue.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the function that prints the print jobs at a rate of 7 pages / min:

```
void Printer::startPrint(PrintJob* current)
{
  int pages = current->getNumPages();
  // print rate in seconds, soit's the same rate as creating print jobs
  double printTime = (pages / PRINT_RATE) * 60; 
  int time = 0;
  int tick = 1;
  while (time < printTime)
  {
    time += tick;
    isFree = false; // printer is busy
  }
  totalTime += printTime / 60;
  isFree = true;
}
```

Here's a link to see the full program: https://onlinegdb.com/ryhudLDbz

Sample input: 4 (generate 4 print jobs)
Sample expected output: 
The print tasks arrived in this order:
87 page(s)
78 page(s)
16 page(s)
23 page(s)

The print tasks were printed in this order:
87 page(s)
16 page(s)
23 page(s)
78 page(s)

Print tasks should be printed in order from least to greatest.

Comment: Can you provide sample input & output you expect

Comment: @bunty I edited my original post to include sample input and expected output.

Comment: You need to execute **startPrint** function in separate thread. By doing this, you will get all 4 "Printing on printer <1/2/3/4>..." messages first, and then get 4 "Printing complete..." messages one by one as soon as printing is completed on respective printers.